# CoreOS on software RAID with EXT4 filesystem

Tags: software-raid, mdadm, coreos

I'm currently thinking about installing the CoreOS on a bare-metal server with two disks I want to put in a software RAID1.

The latest CoreOS is now using EXT4 as their default filesystem and I'm fine with that - I've never used *brtfs* (their previous default) which [apparently supports](https://github.com/coreos/docs/issues/222#issuecomment-68043487) something close to a RAID1, and I'd rather stick to the default EXT4 and `mdadm` with which I already have experience.

I can assemble the RAID using `mdadm` (from a basic Linux environment loaded from the network) but I don't know what to do next, I'm pretty sure the CoreOS installer will wreck everything if I just give it the `/dev/md0` as the target disk so let's not do that.

Did anyone successfully try this ?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use right LABELS:

- Setup SoftwareRAID for the CoreOS **root** partition
- Only for ext4!
- Assume CoreOS is on `/dev/sdaX` and the second RAID Device is `/dev/sdb`
- Drawback: only `/` gets mirrored, Node goes down when sda fails

--

1. Boot into any recovery system like [Grml](http://grml.org)
2. If not already done: [install CoreOS](https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/bare-metal/installing-to-disk/)
3. Backup `/dev/sda9`

   ```
   mkdir -p /root/sda9
   mount /dev/sda9 /mnt
   rsync -a /mnt/* /root/sda9
   umount /dev/sda9
   ```
4. Prepare the partition layout

   ```
   # delete sda9
   sgdisk /dev/sda --delete=9

   # create new /dev/sda9 partition (max size)
   START=`sgdisk /dev/sda -f`
   END=`sgdisk /dev/sda -E`
   sgdisk /dev/sda --new=9:$START:$END --type=9:fd00
   sleep 0.5
   partprobe /dev/sda

   # Remove partition table from sdb
   sgdisk --clear -g /dev/sdb || exit 1

   # create a partition sdb9 with the size of sda9
   PARTDATA=( $(sgdisk -i 9 /dev/sda | grep 'Partition size' || exit 1) )
   SECTORS=$(expr ${PARTDATA[2]} + 2048)
   sgdisk /dev/sdb -a 2048 --new=9:2048:$SECTORS --type=9:fd00 || exit 1
   sleep 0.5
   partprobe /dev/sdb
   ```
5. Create the RAID

   ```
   mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda9 /dev/sdb9
   mkfs.ext4 -I 128 -L ROOT /dev/md0
   ```
6. Copy the Data

   ```
   mount /dev/md0 /mnt
   rsync -a /root/sda9/* /mnt
   umount /mnt
   ```
7. Wait until resync is finished

   watch -n 1 cat /proc/mdstat
8. reboot!

Now we have `ROOT` on `/dev/md0`. I have not tried to put the other partitions (`EFI-SYSTEM`, `BIOS-BOOT`, `USR-A`, `USR-B`, `OEM`, `CONFIG`) on mdadm but it probably would work the same way.

Comment: *Node goes down when sda fails* the whole point of my RAID1 requirement is to have the system continue working until the sysadmins replace the failed drive.

Comment: @André you can try it with the other partitions, just use the right lables

Comment: hi, i have done this, but the problem is that the system does not scan for devices on boot, i have to wait for the emergency console and type `mdadm --assemble --scan` to continue